# How to create a pending order in prestashop

Tags: php, payment-gateway, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Most of the Prestashop payment modules I have come across or any viable tutorial seem to follow the trend of creating and "validating" the order after payment has been ascertained i.e. after the return from a remote payment gateway like PayPal.

We have an architecture that requires we create a traditional "pending" order before payment is even attempted, and then this order's status (history) is changed to "payment accepted" and validated after the payment is completed or otherwise.

Is there a less than complicated way of doing something like this with prestashop?

I have tried calling "**validateOrder**" with a "pending" order status, and I noticed that would fire an order confirmation mail, and empty the contents of the cart irrespective of the payment status.

Comment: Do you want to send the order details to the payment gateway without creating an order and create the order after the payment is completed? This would be more complicated then creating an order with a pending status and updating the status after the payment. You could override `validateOrder` to disable the confirmation mail if that is the only problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the needed order state to ***validateOrder*** method called by the payment gateway module.

```
validateOrder($id_cart, $id_order_state, $amount_paid, $payment_method = 'Unknown', $message = null, $extra_vars = array(), $currency_special = null, $dont_touch_amount = false,   $secure_key = false, Shop $shop = null);
```